Efficient PyTorch band matrix to dense matrix multiplication
Problem: In one of my programs, I need to calculate a matrix multiplication A @ B where both are of size N by N for considerably large N. I'm conjecturing that approximating this product by using band_matrix(A, width) @ B could just suffice the needs, where band_matrix(A, width) denotes a band matrix part of A with width width. For example, width = 0 gives the diagonal matrix with diagonal elements taken from A and width = 1 gives the tridiagonal matrix taken in a similar manner.
My try: I'm trying to extract the tridiagonal matrix, for instance, in the following way:
# Step 1: Extract the main diagonal
main_diag = torch.diagonal(A, dim1=-2, dim2=-1)  # Shape: [d1, d2, N]

# Step 2: Extract the upper diagonal (offset=1)
upper_diag = torch.diagonal(A, offset=1, dim1=-2, dim2=-1)  # Shape: [d1, d2, N-1]

# Step 3: Extract the lower diagonal (offset=-1)
lower_diag = torch.diagonal(A, offset=-1, dim1=-2, dim2=-1)  # Shape: [d1, d2, N-1]

# Step 4: Reconstruct the tridiagonal matrix
# Main diagonal
tridiag = torch.diag_embed(main_diag)  # Shape: [d1, d2, N, N]

# Upper diagonal (shift the values to create the first upper diagonal)
tridiag += torch.diag_embed(upper_diag, offset=1)

# Lower diagonal (shift the values to create the first lower diagonal)
tridiag += torch.diag_embed(lower_diag, offset=-1)

but I'm not sure if tridiag @ B would be much more efficient than the original A @ B or just the same complexity since Torch may not know the specific structure to tridiag. In theory, computation with a tridiagonal matrix should be N times faster.

Any help with understanding PyTorch's behaviour in this type of scenario or implementing some alternative GPU optimized approaches would be greatly appreciated.

did I answer ur question ?

To perform efficient matrix multiplication with a tridiagonal matrix on the GPU using PyTorch, you can try those leads :

Use batched tridiagonal matrix multiplication: PyTorch provides some support for batched operations on banded matrices using torch.bmm (batched matrix-matrix multiplication), but it requires you to handle the band structure yourself. For a tridiagonal matrix, we only need to store the main, upper, and lower diagonals.
Custom implementation with CUDA kernels or use specialized libraries: For more advanced optimization, consider writing custom CUDA kernels for tridiagonal matrix multiplication or use specialized libraries like cuSPARSE or SciPy.

I try an approach of it :
import torch

def band_matrix_mult(A: torch.Tensor, B: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    Multiplies a tridiagonal matrix A with matrix B, assuming A is tridiagonal.
    
    Args:
    - A (torch.Tensor): Tridiagonal matrix of shape (N, N).
    - B (torch.Tensor): Matrix to multiply with A, of shape (N, M).

    Returns:
    - torch.Tensor: Resulting matrix of shape (N, M).
    """
    N, M = B.shape

    # Extract diagonals from A
    main_diag = torch.diagonal(A)  # Shape: [N]
    upper_diag = torch.diagonal(A, offset=1)  # Shape: [N-1]
    lower_diag = torch.diagonal(A, offset=-1)  # Shape: [N-1]

    # Initialize result matrix
    result = torch.zeros_like(B)

    # Multiply main diagonal
    result += main_diag.unsqueeze(-1) * B

    # Multiply upper diagonal
    result[:-1] += upper_diag.unsqueeze(-1) * B[1:]

    # Multiply lower diagonal
    result[1:] += lower_diag.unsqueeze(-1) * B[:-1]

    return result

# Example usage
N = 5
A = torch.tensor([[2., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 2., 3., 0., 0.],
                  [0., 1., 2., 3., 0.],
                  [0., 0., 1., 2., 3.],
                  [0., 0., 0., 1., 2.]])
B = torch.randn((5, 4))

# Efficient tridiagonal multiplication
result = band_matrix_mult(A, B)
print(result)


if we talk about performance :
This custom function leverages the tridiagonal structure for efficiency and should have a time complexity of
(^2⋅), which is significantly better than the (^3) complexity of dense matrix multiplication.
If you're working with extremely large matrices or need even more performance optimization, consider using GPU-based libraries or writing a custom CUDA kernel to take full advantage of GPU parallelism for sparse matrix operations.
